# How can I use Skip functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have implemented an infinity scroll and using it with entity but I would like to transfer that to SQL Server but do not know how to this is my code in entity..

```
     var page = id ?? 1;
        const int recordsPerPage = 10;
        var skipRecords = page * recordsPerPage;

        var listOfProducts = _data.Products.Where(x => x.ProductLine != null); 

         return listOfProducts.
            OrderBy(x=>x.Name).
            Skip(skipRecords).
            Take(recordsPerPage).ToList();
```

I have the other stuff working I just can't seem how to implement the **skip** this is what I have for SQL Server

```
Select top 10  * 
from products 
where ProductLine != null 
order by name
```

It supposed to be such that if were on page 1 then it should show top 10 (1 x 10) and if were on page 2 then it should show top 20 .

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using 2012 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the [OFFSET FETCH Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to do paging if you're willing to let your client maintain state (about how many rows to offset). See the section **Using OFFSET and FETCH to limit the rows returned** in the link referenced.

An example (taken from some MSDN page):

```
--Skip first 10 rows from the sorted result set and return the remaining rows.     
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY col1 OFFSET 10 ROWS;

--Skip first 10 rows from the sorted resultset and return next 5 rows. 
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY col1 OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```